# Initializing char*

Tags: c

When I do this:

```
main(){
   char* output[255];
   output[0] = '\0';
}
```

I get a segfault at `output[0] = '\0'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wow, 6 answers and not a single person has pointed out that this should not segfault.

Comment: @Mysticial Be the first one :-)

Comment: @Mysticial And the one with the most upvotes uses a different language than the question!

Comment: I'll pass... I've got my "Legendary" badge already. So my rep-whoring days are over. :)

Comment: I've already pointed this out

Comment: @peper0 Either I didn't see it, or you edited it in after I made my first comment. But I'll +1 anyway.

Comment: I edited it by adding "Maybe you try to print it somewhere?", but no-segfault note was mentioned earlier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably somewhere else, this part of code shouldn't segfault. Maybe you try to print it somewhere?

However I'm not sure whether it does what you want. You declared array of char pointers:

```
char* output[255];
```

And write char there:

```
output[0] = '\0';
```

You probably wanted to declare array of chars:

```
char output[255];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have created a `char**` type, not a `char*` type.

The correct syntax is `char output[255];`

Answer (score 1):

A better way of doing this is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    char* output = malloc(255); // Allocates the pointer
    output[0] = '\0';
}
```

Sesh's answer is C++.

Answer (score 1):

You want to declare an array of characters, not POINTER to characters. It should be:

```
main(){
       char output[255];
       output[0] = '\0';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable **output** is an array of pointers, not an array of char. Remove the asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

I complied the program that u have posted but apart from warning I was not getting any segfault. its gcc 4.1.2

Answer (score -2):

You are basically declaring an array of pointers (pointers to `char`). And `'\0'` is not a valid value for a pointer. If you intend to allocate 256 `char` memory then rewrite:

```
char* output = new char[256];
```

Comment: How exactly do you use `new` in C? This question isn't about C++.

Comment: Why '\0' is not a valid value for pointer? It just evaluates to NULL which is valid (at least if not dereferenced).

Comment: -1, nothing in this answer is correct. new doesn't exist in C and '\0' is a valid value for a pointer in C (although writing a null pointer with '\0' is very obscure syntax).